# Is there a bonus for scanning an entire planet?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Do you get a units bonus for scanning and uploading all the data about a planet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is definitely a bonus for scanning all animals on a planet. You get a checklist, typically 5-10 different animals with ????. If you scan all of them you can then upload the 100% completed progress bar and get a bonus of about 200,000 credits (25,000 per animal) on top of the basic per-animal credits.

I've found no other bonuses for scanning things other than the basic per-discovery credits. It may not even be possible to upload "all data"; there seem to be a large or infinite number of landmarks on every planet, for instance.

Comment: It also doesn't even show anything past the six most recent landmarks, further suggesting there is no bonus.

Comment: You do not need to scan _all_ animals for the 100% bonus. You only need to complete the list of ????. There may be more species on a planet though.

Answer (score 3):

Post-NEXT answer:

You get bonus nanites (50 per unique species) for uploading a completed planet.