# Are there any bonuses for uploading all data for a Star System?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Per [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281347/is-there-a-bonus-for-scanning-an-entire-planet) question, it goes to say that you will receive bonus units for uploading all of the information on a planet.

As the title says, are there any additional bonuses for uploading all information for a Star System?

Comment: @MageXy I linked that question. The original is asking about a single planet, I am asking about an overall star system

Comment: Since uploads are categorized by planet, and since you can't even click on the individual star system in the menu, the answer is no, you do not receive anything extra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MageXY correctly pointed out, no, there are no bonus units for uploading all data in a single system. The only bonus units you can receive are for cataloguing all unique species on a single planet.

You can still receive units for your discovery, and upload the data and receive units for uploading, but there is no bonus for finding every planet in a system.